# Part Shipment Report in Magento

Tags: magento, report

I have a report to list all orders that are part shipped but the data does not match what I am seeing in the pages Magento generates itelf. My code is below...

```
 $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('state', array('neq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('state', array('neq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('state', array('neq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CLOSED));        

    $collection->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(array('sfsg' => $collection->getTable('sales/shipment')), 'main_table.increment_id = sfsg.increment_id', array('shipped'=>'sfsg.created_at'))
    ->where('sfsg.created_at IS NOT NULL');        
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
```

So the first part defines that no orders with a status of complete, canceled or closed are selected eg orders that are part shipped and the leftJoin bit joins the sales_flat_shipment table on increment_id (order id). This then pulls out created_at which is when the shipment was created/sent.

This produces my report no bother but the data inside it does not match what I see if I look at a report using Magento's built in facilities.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong here? It must be the lefJoin that is not right I'm thinking. If anyone has any useful documentation on this I can read that would be much appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0):

The above will work if you replace the line

```
->joinLeft(array('sfsg' => $collection->getTable('sales/shipment')), 'main_table.increment_id = sfsg.increment_id', array('shipped'=>'sfsg.created_at'))
```

with

```
->joinLeft(array('sfsg' => $collection->getTable('sales/shipment')), 'main_table.entity_id = sfsg.order_id', array('shipped'=>'sfsg.created_at'))
```

Weirdly, Magento has decided to name the columns that match the 2 tables entity_id and order_id.

Any explanation of this would be appreciated.